# os.chdir() to relative home directory (/home/usr/)

Tags: python, bash, shell, chdir

Is there a way to use os.chdir() to go to relative user folder?

I'm making a bash and the only issue I found is the `cd ~`, `arg[0]` is undefined since I'm using this cd functions:

```
def cd(args):
    os.chdir(args[0])
    return current_status
```

Which I want to change to

```
def cd(args):
    if args[0] == '~':
        os.chdir('/home/') 
# Here I left it to /home/ since I don't know how 
# to get the user's folder name
    else:
        os.chdir(args[0])
    return current_status
```

Comment: You can parse environment variable `$HOME`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `os.chdir` won't do that, since it is just a thin wrapper around a system call.  Consider that `~` is actually a legal name for a directory.

You can, however, use `os.expanduser` to expand `~` in a path.

```
def cd(path):
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(path))
```

Note that this will also expand `~user` to the home directory for `user`.

Comment: Which is more broadly applicable too, it handles paths relative to the user home (`~/private/dir`) and (to an extent) handles other user home relative paths too (`~otheruser/public/dir`).

Comment: Why is ~ returning path not found error? I'll review my code and edit my question.